# Messy javascript as long as it works, does it matter?

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding the act of breaking the laws of javascript (Don't repeat code, etc) and that is, does it really matter as long as the performance and functionality isn't affected in anyway?

I have a script with 200+ line of code that looks messy after I did some work arounds, made it compatible with every browser and bugtested it a few times, and even after that it still runs pretty great even if the code isn't as organized. I haven't run into any errors with it yet and the load time is supreme. I should also note that I learned javascript a few weeks ago, so I am not perfect at it.

I do understand that if you're writing a huge applicaton it may have a noticeable impact on the performance and load time.

This has been on my mind for a few days and I just wanted to see your opinion about it, so please post a detailed opinion and maybe some tips and tricks as your answer. Thank you. :)

Comment: Performance isn't really related to how organized the code is. But if it is messy and hard to maintain you will most likely have bugs when adding a new feature

Comment: The problem generally isn't performance, but maintenance. If it's messy and you repeat tons of code it can get very difficult to maintain and add new features.

Comment: Does it matter, to who?  To the browser? no.  To your future self, to your coworkers, etc...?  Almost definitely.

Comment: *Always assume the maintenance programmer is a homicidal maniac that knows where you live*. Also, it **might** just be you six months (or years) from now.

Comment: I couldn't publish my answer on time, so here's my two cents:

Comment: Code organization and patterns are not focused solely on making your code run smooth and fast. You should think "If someone else is going to upgrade this code in a few weeks/months/years how will they do it?" (specially since that someone else might be you, and you won't remember 90% the things you did, trust me).
So yes you should worry about the organization of your code.

Comment: (part 2) 
I would recommend that you research and read a bit about programming patterns. They can be applied to any language, so it's knowledge that's transferable wherever you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it matters.  A lot.

You cite performance and download time as if they were the most important things.

I'd say that readable code that's easily understood by others might be more important than your measures.

Keeping code DRY, organized, neat, and readable are the signs of a professional in my view.  Sloppy, copy & paste messes come from hacks.